# How do update a web page asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have a .net 4.0 multi-tiered web app. I have a very long process running and I just need to update the user as the records process...using just a simple message to the screen.

In the business logic I have some async calls going on. If I actually step through the code, it seems to do what it needs to do...after it hits the lengthy process it appears to spawn a new thread to update the front end. In the UI I have a literal in an Update Panel and the code to run it:

```
FileApplicationTests fileApplicationPageTest = new FileApplicationTests(); 
fileApplicationPageTest.OnReadyToBeDisplayed += new  DisplayMessageEventHandler(WriteToLog);

private void WriteToLog(object sender, string log_entry)
{
    Literal1.Text += log_entry + "<br/>";
}
```

As I said, I can step through this and all appears fine...but the web page itself is not updated until the end.

Here is the middle tier....

```
public delegate void DisplayMessageEventHandler(object sender, string msg);

public class FileApplicationTests
{
        public event DisplayMessageEventHandler OnReadyToBeDisplayed;

        public string FileApplication()
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            FileApplicationFrameWork filer = new FileApplicationFrameWork();
            filer.OnRecordProcessed += new ProcessedEventHandler(PrintMsg);
            filer.FileApplicationWithoutRegistering();                  

            return msg;
        }

        private void PrintMsg(object sender, string msg)
        {
            OnReadyToBeDisplayed(this, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

and the UI:

```
FileApplicationTests fileApplicationPageTest = new FileApplicationTests();   

fileApplicationPageTest.OnReadyToBeDisplayed += new DisplayMessageEventHandler(WriteToLog);
fileApplicationPageTest.FileApplication(); 

private void WriteToLog(object sender, string log_entry)
{
    Literal1.Text += log_entry + "<br/>"; 
}
```

Comment: What does your js look like on the web page?

Comment: Do you want execute some method on the code behing in every time ?

Comment: No javascript. I thought wrapping it in the UpdatePanel forced all updates automatically.

Comment: The user clicks a button which heads to the back end and loops through, processing records. Each records take a long time to process. Each time it is finished, I just want to send a message to the front end saying Completed.

Comment: show all relevant code.. also you can do this using jquery or AJax or even basic javascript in regards to displaying a message dlg showing `Completed!`

Comment: UpdatePanel will just update itself when the request ends, it doesn't update itself while it's running. You'd need AJAX/SignalR type of solution to handle that.